# How Do I Switch Between Multiple Eclipse Windows (in "Split Screen" Mode)

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse allows you to open more than one text editing "window" at a time to get a "split screen" effect.  This is great, but the problem I'm having is that there doesn't **seem** to be any way to switch between these windows, directly.

Now, you can use the usual commands (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>ALT+RIGHT</kbd>, etc.) to switch between specific buffers.  In other words, if I have window 1 with A.java and B.java open, and window 2 with C.java open, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to go from A, to B, to C.  However, I can't just go from A or B (ie. from window 1) in to C (ie. to window 2), unless I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and type in "C.java".

There are half a million Eclipse commands though, and they're certainly not all labeled consistently, so it's quite possible I'm just failing to find the relevant command.  Does anyone out there in SO-land happen to know it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default, its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. However, its useful if you map you keys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between open editors like Windows.

You can change your preferred keys in  `Window>Preferences>General>Keys` and change "Next Editor" to any key of your choice(Ex: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks, but CTRL+F6 is basically the same as CTRL+e, in that it gives you a list of open editors to choose from; the only difference is that CTRL+F6 lists all of the editors in both windows (CTRL+e only lists the current windows').  I'm looking for a command that just switches between Eclipse windows in the same way that ALT+TAB switches between actual (OS) windows (without me having to pick anything from a list).

Comment: I have Aptana installed, and they have their own "next editor" also.  However, even when I use the Aptana "next editor" (which is mapped to CTRL+TAB), it still isn't quite what I'm looking for.  It goes to the next editor, without prompting for a list, which is good.  However, it just goes to the next editor, in either window, not to the current editor in the next window, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+F6 just once also switches between two alternate windows as I can see which is same as windows default action of Alt+Tab. However if there are multiple windows open, obviously it'll ask u to choose which one to jump into. Or is there something else which I m not able to understand? Can u upload a screenshot of what kind of switching u r referring to.

Comment: Ahhhh ... when I was doing it I was seeing the list pop up, so I was trying to select from it; I didn't realize I could just let go and have it switch.  Thanks!

Comment: Now in Eclipse Mars Ctrl + F6 seems to no longer work. It still just switches between buffers. But the plugin "HandySplit" mentioned in an answer below works

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved easily if you are using Vrapper in Eclipse. [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)
 is a Vim plugin for Eclipse. If you are trying to maximize your productivity in Eclipse like we all are, it's well worth the try.

Once you got it installed, check out the [Split Editor Plugin](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?page=10) for Vrapper. You can then create splits on the fly and switch between them using the standard Vim shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl-w w</kbd>

Bonus: don't forget to maxmize your editors using <kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>.
 If your editor ever loses focus for some reason, regain it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-F12</kbd>
Finally open any file in your project using <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-r</kbd>

Edit from anula comment:
A useful thing to mention here: Ctrl-w by default binds to closing window, so if you want to use it as in Vim you need to first go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys and unbind "Close".

Comment: Thanks a lot. An useful thing to mention here: Ctrl-w is by default binded to closing window, so if you want to use it as in Vim you need to first go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys and unbind "Close".

Answer (score 6):

You can install the HandySplit plugin from Eclipse Marketplace and bind its 'Toggle focus between split editors' command to any keyboard shortcut you like.

Comment: This worked for me in Eclipse Mars. The default shortcut Ctrl + F6 is not working.